# Showing that $\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty a_j=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty b_k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Show when $\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty a_j$ is absolute convergent, than $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty b_k$ with $b_k:=(a_0+2a_1+...+2^ka_k)/2^{k+1}$ is also absolute convergent,

and even $\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty a_j=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty b_k$

---

**My attempt:**

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty b_k=\frac{a_0}{2}+\left(\frac{a_0}{2^2}+\frac{2a_1}{2^2}\right)+\left(\frac{a_0}{2^3}+\frac{a_1}{2^3}+\frac{2^2a_2}{2^3}\right)+...=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left (\sum\limits_{i=0}^k \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}2^ia_i\right)$

$$\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left |\sqrt[k]{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k} \left ( \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}2^ia_i\right)}\right|=0<1$$

Because  $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left |\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k} \left ( \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}2^ia_i\right)\right|=\left |\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \left ( 0*2^ia_i\right)\right|=0$

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left (\sum\limits_{i=0}^k \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}2^ia_i\right)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty b_k$ is absolute convergent

Since $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty b_k$ is absolute convergent, we can rearrange its pieces:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty b_k=\frac{a_0}{2}+\left(\frac{a_0}{2^2}+\frac{2a_1}{2^2}\right)+\left(\frac{a_0}{2^3}+\frac{2a_1}{2^3}+\frac{2^2a_2}{2^3}\right)+...=a_0\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+...\right)+a_1\left(\frac{2}{2^2}+\frac{2}{2^3}+\frac{2}{2^4}+...\right)+...$$

$$=a_0\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\right)+2a_1\left(\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\right)+2^2a_2\left(\sum\limits_{k=3}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\right)+...$$

$=a_0\left(2-1\right)+2a_1\left(2-1-\frac{1}{2}\right)+2^2a_2\left(2-1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+...=a_0+\frac{1}{2}2a_1+\frac{1}{4}2^2a_2+...=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k$

$\Box$

---

Hello could someone look over my work and give some feedback :)? Is my solution correct, and if not, what could I improve?

Comment: We have $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } \sum\limits_{i = 0}^k {\frac{1}{{2^{k + 1} }}2^i a_i }  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } \frac{1}{{2^{k + 1} }}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } \sum\limits_{i = 0}^k {2^i a_i } .
$$ The first limit is indeed $0$, but do you know anything about the second one? It might tend to infinity faster than $2^{k+1}$ and hence the whole limit will not be $0$.

Comment: But every piece of the sum will be multiplied with $\frac{1}{2^{\infty}}$? Or am i wrong? I though any piece will be multiplied by zero and since $a_j \rightarrow 0$ this should mean the limit is 0?

Comment: @CoffeeArabica The first limit converges to $0$. If the second one converges to $0$, then yes, the product will be zero. But if the second one converges to $+\infty$, we have the indeterminate form $0 \cdot \infty$. It is indeterminate because it can be $0$, a finite number or $+\infty$. If you can prove that the second limit converges to some finite number, then you can proceed with your claim.

Comment: @CoffeeArabica Unfortunately, there is no way to prove that the second limit converges to some finite number for all absolute convergent series $\sum a_{i}$. For instance, if you take $a_{i} = \frac{1}{i}$. even if $a_{i} = \frac{1}{i} \to 0$, the series $\sum 2^{i} a_{i}$ diverges because the general term $2^{i} a_{i} =\frac{2^{i}}{i}$ does not converge to $0$.

Comment: @CoffeeArabica Note that the number of terms you multiply by $1/2^{k+1}$ is incresing too (there are $k$ such terms).

Answer (score 1):

When you want to prove the absolute convergence of the series $\sum_k b_k$ you should prove that $\sum_k |b_k|$ is finite. When you only have non-negative terms, you can rearrange them in any order. Here

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty |b_k| &= \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left |\sum\limits_{i=0}^k \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}2^ia_i\right|
\leq \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{i=0}^k \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}2^i |a_i|
= \sum_{0 \leq i \leq k} \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}2^i |a_i| \\
&=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty 2^i |a_i| \underbrace{\left (\sum\limits_{k=i}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\right)}_{=\frac{1}{2^j}}
= \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty |a_i| < \infty
\end{aligned}
$$

so the series $\sum_k b_k$ is absolutely convergent. Once you have proved this, you are guaranteed that you can rearrange the terms with $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty b_k$ so the same computations works, but you have an equality instead of an inequality in the second step so you get that $\sum_k b_k = \sum_k a_k$.