# Absolute convergence of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{-(k+1)}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k}2^ja_j$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

> Let be $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ an absolutely convergent series and $b_k:=2^{-(k+1)}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k}2^ja_j$. Show that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}b_k$ converges absolutely.

Comment: When you move the $2^{-k}$ inside the sum, only the $2^j$ changes. The subscript on $a_j$ does not change to $a_{k-j}$; it stays $a_j$.

Comment: Appears already [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3731457).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_j$ are nonnegative real numbers, then we're free to change the order $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{j=0}^k=\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=j}^\infty$: $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k-1}\sum_{j=0}^k 2^j a_j=\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^j a_j\underbrace{\sum_{k=j}^\infty 2^{-k-1}}_{=2^{-j}}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j.$$

For the general case, we use $|b_k|\leqslant 2^{-k-1}\sum\limits_{j=0}^k 2^j|a_j|$ and the above to get $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty|b_k|\leqslant\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty|a_j|$.

Comment: ... and conclude that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty b_k=\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty a_j$.

Comment: Nice answer ...

Comment: @metamorphy $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k-1}\sum_{j=0}^k 2^j a_j=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^k 2^{j-k-1}a_j=\cdots$$holds because the latter $\sum\limits_{j=0}^k$ simply denotes a sum (finitely many summands). $$\cdots=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=j}^{\infty} 2^{j-k-1}a_j=\cdots$$holds because $2^{j-k-1}a_j\geq0$ allows for interchanging the summation. $$\cdots=\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{j}a_j\sum_{k=j}^{\infty} 2^{-k-1}=\cdots$$ holds because $2^{j}$ and $a_j$ are independent of $k$. Are those intermediate steps correctly understood?

Answer (score 1):

I just want to share another answer which uses Cauchy's product rule ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20more%20specifically%20in,French%20mathematician%20Augustin%20Louis%20Cauchy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20more%20specifically%20in,French%20mathematician%20Augustin%20Louis%20Cauchy.)).

We know that $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}a_j$ and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{-k-1}$ are both absolute convergent. Therefore we are allowed to apply Cauchy's product rule:

$1\cdot\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}a_j=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{-k-1}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}a_j=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k}a_j2^{-(k-j)-1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k}2^{j-(k+1)}a_j=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}b_k$.

Hence, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}b_k$ converges absolutely and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}b_k=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}a_j$.